# Ubuntu with headless server + access with VNC at startup is not possible

Tags: linux, vnc, ubuntu-20.04, headless

ubuntu desktop 20.04 LTS installed. system is up and running, access over VNC is possible **as long as** i did a login at the desktop **upfront**. vnc service by vino.

i want to use the system headless: without any connected monitor. vnc access by client should be possible after a reboot.

read several threads in the web, tried to setup a

- dummy driver by xserver-xorg-video-dummy
- plus configfile in xorg.conv

this does **not** work. i assume the reason is that vino is not running.

any idea how to start the vnc server during startup and add a virtual display? thanks for your support.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use autologin? You can simply use a systemd unit to start the VNC server.

Comment: i tried that: without a physical monitor at startup & autologin enabled: my screen is black when i access the system with vnc.